# How to stream a map with a values Stream<String> using Stream API?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the map `Map<String, Stream<String>>`. I need to build sorted stream of all participants without duplication, ignore null or empty strings, trim extra spaces and modify each to [Title Case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_case).

For example, for a given map:

```
{
  "A"=["B", "C", " D  "],
  "B"=["kas", "B", "c ", "dddd"]
}
```

I should get:

```
["B", "C", "D", "Dddd", "Kas"]
```

I need to create method like this:

```
public Stream<String> listN(Map<String, Stream<String>> map) {
    map.values().stream()... ?
}
```

but I don't even know how to start.

Comment: Your Map is not a very good idea. A Stream can only be used once. It would be better to have `Map<String, Suppler<Stream<String>>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stream the map's values, flapMap to stream of Strings, then apply the various filters and modifications, distinct, sort:

```
public Stream<String> listN(Map<String, Stream<String>> map) {
    return map.values().stream()
      .flatMap(s -> s)
      .filter(Objects::nonNull)
      .filter(Predicate.not(String::isBlank))
      .map(String::trim)
      .map(String::toLowerCase)
      .map(s -> s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1))
      .distinct()
      .sorted();
}
```

See [live demo](https://onecompiler.com/java/3z8t4skya).

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right and you don’t need to use the map’s keys, then you can use the map’s values() method, use flatMap over them to flatten the results (you may have to map the lists to a stream first), and then you can use sorted(), and finally distinct(), all Stream’s methods.

Comment: thank you for the idea, but how can I ignore extra spaces and case sensitivity?

Answer (score 0):

Your question and your method name seem to indicate that you want to return a list rather than a stream.  Perhaps you also also meant to use a `Map<String, List<String>>` (but then I don't know your use case). In any event, this returns a `List<String>` but more importantly it demonstrates the suggestion by [@user20742](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/user207421) to use a `Map<String, Supplier<Stream<String>>>` so that the Map can be repeatedly used, if required. Otherwise, the map would only survive one calling and the streams would be exhausted.

```
Map<String, Supplier<Stream<String>>> map = Map.of("A",
        () -> Stream.of("B", "C", " D ",null), "B",
        () -> Stream.of("kas", "B", "c ", "dddd"));

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    List<String> list = listN(map);
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

prints

```
[B, C, D, Dddd, Kas]
[B, C, D, Dddd, Kas]
[B, C, D, Dddd, Kas]
```

With the original map, it would print once and then throw an `IllegalStateException` showing the streams have been used.

The modified method below returns a list using the described map. Since the method doesn't appear to be using `instance fields` I have declared it `static`.
Except for some slight modifications, this uses the same constructs that are used in [Bohemian's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76267187/1552534) answer. The main difference is the `.get()` call to retrieve the stream from the supplier.

```
public List<String> listN(Map<String, Supplier<Stream<String>>> map) {
   return map.values().stream().flatMap(a -> a.get())
           .filter(str-> str != null && !str.isBlank())
           .map(a -> {
               a = a.trim();
               return a.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + a.substring(1);
           }).distinct().sorted().toList();
}
```